# Hosting workflow durable duplex services in console host

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm using WF 4.0 for building workflows and I just want to know is it possible to host a workflow duplex service that uses wsHttpContextBinding using console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, WF4 doesn't require a specific application type as host and neither does WCF.